# Multiple radio buttons - Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, radio-button

So I'm pretty retarded at this sort of stuff, this is my first attempt at coding something so here goes:

This is in my view:

```
<?php
echo form_open();
echo form_radio('name1', '1'). " 1";
echo form_radio('name1', '2'). " 2";
echo form_radio('name1', '3'). " 3";

echo form_radio('name2', '1'). " 1";
echo form_radio('name2', '2'). " 2";
echo form_radio('name2', '3'). " 3";

echo form_radio('name3', '1'). " 1";
echo form_radio('name3', '2'). " 2";
echo form_radio('name3', '3'). " 3";
echo form_submit('vote', 'Submit!');
echo form_close(); 
?>
```

This is in my controller:

```
if ($this->input->post('vote')) {
 $this->My_model->do_something();
}
```

This is the final bit i need done for my little script, i want 3 different variables from the radio box's to my controller then my model but I'm not quite sure how to do it and CI just confuses me sometimes.

Help!

Answer (score 4):

```
$name1 = $this->input->post('name1');
$name2 = $this->input->post('name2');
$name3 = $this->input->post('name3');

if ($this->input->post('vote')) {
    $this->My_model->do_something($name1, $name2, $name3);
}
```

With radio buttons, if there are multiple with the same name, only one of that name can be selected.  The above 3 lines should return a 1, 2, or 3 for each of the 3 sets of radio buttons.

EDIT: To check for duplicate values in PHP, you can use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array_unique).

```
$names = array($name1, $name2, $name3);
$uniqueNames = array_unique($names);
if($names == $uniqueNames){
    // No duplicate values
}
else{
    // Duplicate values
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But for the duplicate thing each have the same values so for instance - you choose 1 1 2 - 1 would be a duplicate

Comment: Yes, 1 would be a duplicate... and?

Comment: I want all 3 of them to be different

Comment: Please see the edited answer.  I suggest checking for duplicates using JavaScript, though.  A jQuery example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/6RbNg/1

Comment: @Rocket You should never rely fully on JavaScript to validate your forms.

Comment: @treeface, true.  You should use PHP to validate the forms, but you can use the JavaScript to kinda pre-validate before sending it to PHP.

Comment: @Rocket I agree, of course. JS validation for the people who play nice and PHP validation for the troublesome users. :-]

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

```
$btnNo1 = $this->input->post('name1');
$btnNo2 = $this->input->post('name2');
$btnNo3 = $this->input->post('name3');

$this->load->model('My_model');
$this->My_model->do_something($btnNo1,$btnNo2,$btnNo3);
```

In model:

```
class My_model extends Model{

    function My_model(){
        parent::Model();
    }

    public function do_something($btn1,$btn2,$btn3){
        //do some stuff with you btn values
    }
}
```

Comment: You have access to `$this->input->post()` in your Model. So instead of passing btnNo 1 to 3 to your Model, fetch the data in your Model. This way, it will be easier in the future, if you want to add, say, a btnNo4. Just my thoughts